# CSS Dropdown menu is not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

I am having some kind of problem with my css and I am really frustrated over this ?
**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hawa</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav {background: #008080;position:relative;}
#nav ul {list-style:none;display:flex;position:relative;}
#nav ul li {width: 50px;display:inline-table;padding: 10px 20px;position:relative;}
#nav ul li:hover {background:#333;}
#nav ul li:hover > ul {display: block;position:absolute;margin-left:0px;width:100%;}
#nav ul li a{text-decoration:none;font-family:Verdana;color:#fff;}
#nav ul ul {display:none;}
#nav ul ul li {background: #008080;}
```

My problem is :

- My css drop down is not aligning with the li element.

Can anyone help me out ?

[image: CSS Dropdown]

Comment: add padding to anchors not to list check my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, there was a "padding" on your submenu list

```
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
     display: block;
     position:absolute;
     left:0px;
     width:100%;
     padding-left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use negative margin value  http://jsfiddle.net/5tz0zszy/

I've made a bit change in the css

```
#nav {
background: #008080;
position:relative;
}
#nav ul {
list-style:none;
display:flex;
position:relative;
}
#nav ul li {
width: 50px;
display:inline-table;
padding: 10px 20px;
position:relative;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
background:#333;
}
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
position:absolute;
margin-left:-60px;width:100%;
}
#nav ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Verdana;
color:#fff;
}
#nav ul ul {
display:none;
}
#nav ul ul li {
background: #008080;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

RESET YOUR CSS `*{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0; margin:0;}`

add padding to `anchors` not to `list`

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljaaubny/4/)

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0; margin:0;}
#nav {background: #008080;position:relative;}
#nav ul {display:flex;position:relative;}
#nav ul li {list-style:none;float:left;position:relative;}
#nav ul li:hover {background:#333;}
#nav ul li > ul {position:absolute;}
#nav ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
#nav a{text-decoration:none;font-family:Verdana;color:#fff;display:block;clear:both;padding: 10px 20px;}
#nav ul ul {display:none;position: absolute;left: 0;}
#nav ul ul li {background: #008080;display:block;width:100%;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple add this:

```
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0px;
    width:100%;
    left: 0;/*Add this*/
    padding: 0;/*Add this*/
    top: 40px;/*Add this*/
}
```

Also change to `display: block` `#nav ul li {width: 50px;display:block;padding: 10px 20px;position:relative;}`. Check resume menu.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zd6tc23/4/)

Comment: Yeah man thanks!! but I did top:100% :). Appriciate that though !!